# setState doesn't do what it suppose to

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing a really strange bug which i have never seen before. 
I fetch the data from server and i get an array of objects then I'm trying to setState with fetched data but my state is empty! Help someone please.
[image]

Comment: It would be preferable if you posted your code as text, not in image form(See [mcve]).

Comment: setState is async, so the effects won't be seen immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Updating state in React is not a sync operation.
It's async for optimization (to group changes together and change state only once).

You can use `useEffect` to react on changes:

```js
useEffect(() => { console.log(state)}, [state])
```

or you can just show your `state` inside of `return` (`return` calls every time when component re-renders, component rerenders because of `useState` calls).

Answer (score 0):

Updating state in react is an asynchronous operation. You should instead log out data in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state)
}, [state]);
```